# How to remove duplicate elements for two numpy arrays in python

Tags: python, numpy, duplicates, element

I have two array naming u,v,
e.g.

```
u=np.array([1.0,2.0,2.0,3.0,4.0])
v=np.array([10.0,21.0,18.0,30.0,40.0])
a=np.array([100.0,210.0,220.0,300.0,400.0])
```

If two elements in u are same, then delete that one which is higher in v value.
For the above example,the result should be

```
u_new=np.array([1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0])
v_new=np.array([10.0,18.0,30.0,40.0])
a_new=np.array([100.0,220.0,300.0,400.0])

def remove_duplicates(u,v,a):
    u_new, indices = np.unique(u, return_index=True)
    v_new = np.zeros(len(u_new), dtype=np.float64)
    a_new = np.zeros(len(u_new), dtype=np.float64)
    for i in range(len(indices)):
        j1 = indices[i]
        if i < len(indices) - 1:
            j2 = indices[i + 1]
        else:
            j2 = j1 + 1
        v_new[i] = np.amin(v[j1:j2])
        k = np.argmin(v[j1:j2]) + j1
        a_new[i] = a[k]

    return u_new,v_new,a_new
```

The above code has a problem when treat floating number because there is not exact equality between two floating number. So I have to change it to a very 'stupid' way

```
def remove_duplicates(u, v, a):
    u_new=u
    v_new=v
    a_new=a
    cnt = 0
    for i in range(len(u)):
        if cnt <1:
            u_new[cnt] = u[i]
            v_new[cnt] = v[i]
            a_new[cnt] = a[i]
            cnt += 1
        else:
            if abs(u[i]-u_new[cnt-1]) > 1e-5:
                u_new[cnt] = u[i]
                v_new[cnt] = v[i]
                a_new[cnt] = a[i]
                cnt += 1
            else:
                print("Two points with same x coord found.ignore", i)
                if v_new[cnt-1] > v[i]:
                    v_new[cnt-1] = v[i]
                    a_new[cnt-1] = a[i]

    return u_new[:cnt], v_new[:cnt], a_new[:cnt]
```

How can I program it in a Pythonic way?
Thank you.

Comment: Constructing a new array, by looping over the first two arrays seems most feasible to me. I think no in-place operation is preferable.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I want more python-like code to do this as the loop on array is time-consuming I think.

Comment: Are the arrays always 1D and sorted as per your example?

Comment: Yes, they are always 1D array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kinda cheeky to change your question, but here goes.

```
def remove_duplicates(u,v,a,d=1e-5):
    s=np.argsort(u)
    ud=abs(u[s][1:]-u[s][:-1])<d
    vd=v[s][1:]<v[s][:-1]
    drop=np.union1d(s[:-1][ud&vd],s[1:][ud&~vd])
    return np.delete(u,drop),np.delete(v,drop),np.delete(a,drop)
```

That should work with a threshhold value to clean up your floats.

Comment: This is the most concise and easy-understand  method I think. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zip`, `sorted` and `groupby` functions:

```
from itertools import groupby
u1, v1 = zip(*[next(g) for k, g in groupby(sorted(zip(u, v)), key = lambda x: x[0])])
# note here use next to take the first element(smaller v value) from each group    

u1
# (1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0)

v1
# (10.2, 22.0, 28.0, 41.0)
```

Comment: very beautiful solution. Thank you a lot.

Comment: When the numpy array elements are float numbers, the method above will  have problem because the comparison between two float numbers is not exact without tolerance given. How can I give the tolerance and make it works? Thank you.

Comment: I think you can round the key to the precision you wanted. `u1, v1 = zip(*[next(g) for k, g in groupby(sorted(zip(u, v)), key = lambda x: round(x[0], 10))])` for instance.

Comment: Rouding the float to some precision is an alternative method for this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**Approach #1 :** Here's an approach for floating-pt numbers by slitting into groups of *tolerable* (by given tolerance value) proximity -

```
tol = 1e-5 # Set tolerance for floating pt number match
A = np.split( v, np.flatnonzero(np.diff(u) > tol)+1)
lens = np.array(list(map(len,A)))
idx = np.array([np.argmax(i) for i in A]) 
idx[1:] += lens[:-1].cumsum()
m = ~np.in1d(np.arange(a.size), idx[lens>1])
u_new, v_new, a_new = u[m], v[m], a[m]
```

Sample input, output -

```
In [143]: u=np.array([1.0,2.0,2.00000001,3.0,3.9999998, 4.0, 4.00000001])
     ...: v=np.array([10.0,21.0,18.0,30.0,36.0, 40.0, 38.0])
     ...: a=np.array([100.0,210.0,220.0,300.0,77.0, 400.0, 67.00])
     ...: 

In [144]: u_new
Out[144]: array([ 1.        ,  2.00000001,  3.        ,  3.9999998 ,  4.00000001])

In [145]: v_new
Out[145]: array([ 10.,  18.,  30.,  36.,  38.])

In [146]: a_new
Out[146]: array([ 100.,  220.,  300.,   77.,   67.])
```

**Approach #2 :** Here's another approach without splitting and as such must be more efficient -

```
u_idx = np.append(False, np.diff(u) > tol).cumsum()
max_idx = (np.append(np.unique(u_idx, return_index=1)[1], u_idx.size)-1)[1:]
sidx = (v.max()*u_idx + v).argsort()
m = ~np.in1d(np.arange(a.size), sidx[max_idx][np.bincount(u_idx)>1])
u_new, v_new, a_new = u[m], v[m], a[m]
```

Comment: Thank you for your two approaches. I believe both of them will work well though I am not sure I can understand them thoroughly.