# How to reference a slice/view of a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, slice

An answer I gave [earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40986312/how-to-remove-duplicate-elements-for-two-numpy-arrays-in-python/40990181#40990181) raised a question for me:  Is it possible to reference a view or slice of a numpy array without repeating a bunch of brackets?

For instance, in the answer I used `s=np.argsort(u)` and then did all my calculations on a 'virtually' sorted `u[s]`.  I've had situations where I then needed a boolean mask of that array, giving something akin to `u[s][mask]`.  For bigger data I might have a mask of a mask of a mask . . . until things start to look like the end of an episode of Scooby Doo.

But if I assign that array to a variable `b=a[s][mask]` and change `b`, `a` does not change, so I end up carrying a pile of brackets through my calculations.  I've tried various arrangements of `uv=u.view()[s]` but it seems `.view()` only makes a view of the whole array.  Is there another method I am missing?

Comment: The issue is `[mask]`. Since it makes an arbitrary subset of the array `a`, it always returns a new array, not a view. Can you avoid making a mask in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may not be able to solve the simple case of `u[s]` but in more complex cases like `u[s][mask]` you can:

```
t = s[mask]
u[t] # same as u[s][mask]
```

That is, you can simplify your mask to a single variable, but you may not be able to get rid of it completely, unless perhaps you want to write your own wrapper class with `__getitem__` and `__setitem__`.

Comment: But if I only have masks?  I guess I could do `t=np.indices(u.shape)[mask1][mask2][mask3]`.  I assume it ends up being the same problem `pandas` has where at some layer of abstraction it get tough to tell the difference between a slice and a copy without something like `.loc` to differentiate

Comment: @DanielForsman: Yeah.  In your question you mentioned `s=np.argsort(u)` which is not a mask, but an array of indices.  I worked from that assumption.  If you have lots of masks you can compose them and just use the composed version on the original array.